# How can I merge before move files?

Tags: bash, awk, merge

I have some files (few millions) and I keep file list in files.txt like this:

```
/home/user/1.txt
/home/user/2.txt
/home/user/3.txt
/home/user/4.txt
/home/user/5.txt
```

I need to move all, but before move I must merge too.

I can move like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for files in $(cat files.txt); do
    mv $files /home/user/hop/
done
```

I can merge all with `cat *` but I need to merge by twos, like this:

```
1.txt and 2.txt merge --> 1.txt and move.
3.txt and 4.txt merge --> 3.txt and move.
5.txt                 --> 5.txt and move.
```

But I must merge before move, in /home/user/, not in /home/user/hop/

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by merge? Append content of 2.txt at the end of 1.txt?

Comment: @SMA, yes, like `echo 2.txt >> 1.txt`

Comment: cat the two file names at a time ?

Comment: It's example, I have few million lines in files.txt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$ cat file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 > out.txt` after you moved them, with this you can also set the order of the files to be merged.

Also works for binaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
while read -r f; do
   if ((++i % 2)); then
      p="$f"
   else
      cat "$f" >> "$p"
      mv "$p" /home/user/hop/
      rm "$f"
      unset p
   fi
done < list.txt

[[ -n $p ]] && mv "$p" /home/user/hop/
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I need to remove files after merge and move. This is keep `2.txt` and `4.txt` in `/home/user`. And could you please help me for `% 2`? Can I increase this number like 5,10,100?

Comment: Yes I know you have not downvoted. I added `rm` command to remove the even # file from source folder. You can of course change `2` to `5` but then make sure to store 4 previous files in an array and then remove them all after appending into 5th file.